# Adding _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS definition using cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

Is it possible to add `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` preprocessor definition using cmake?

```
add_definitions(-CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
add_definitions(-_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
add_definitions(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
```

These are what I've tried so far. None of these attempts were successful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this:

```
if(MSVC)
    add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
endif()
```

See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_definitions.html) for the official documentation.
The general form is:

```
add_definitions(-DFOO -DBAR ...)
```

Note that, if it's intended for a single target, you should rather use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_compile_definitions.html).

Comment: also notice `target_compile_definitions` populate [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS) so you must use `VAR` or `VAR=value`